# SQL Server: advanced update query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need some help on sql update query that calculate estimated daily stock consumption ,

At first I fill table with day requirement .

```
declare  @stock TABLE ([StockDate] [datetime] NULL,
                       [stock] [int])

insert into @stock 
values ('2017/21/03', -3), ('2017/22/03', -1),
       ('2017/23/03', -5), ('2017/24/03', 0),
       ('2017/25/03', -4), ('2017/26/03', -7),
       ('2017/27/03', 0);
```

- Initial stock : 12
- Order quantity: 10
- Order Point   : 3
- for 21/03/2017  stock =   12-3 = 9
- for 22/03/2017  stock =   9-1 = 8
- for 23/03/2017  stock =   8-5 = 3 <= OrderPoint (3) 
  then stock = 8-5 + 10 = 13

I tried :

```
update s
set s.stock = case 
                 when s.StockDate = '2017/21/03' 
                    then 12 
                    else s2.stock 
              end + s.stock
from @stock s 
left join @stock s2 on s2.StockDate = DATEADD(day, -1, s.StockDate)
```

Actual results :

```
Date                    Stock
2017-03-21 00:00:00.000 9
2017-03-22 00:00:00.000 -4
2017-03-23 00:00:00.000 -6
2017-03-24 00:00:00.000 -5
2017-03-25 00:00:00.000 -4
2017-03-26 00:00:00.000 -11
2017-03-27 00:00:00.000 -7
```

the probleme that is the day -1 not calculated yet and gives wrong results on that query.

Expected results :

---

```
Date                    Stock
2017-03-21 00:00:00.000 9
2017-03-22 00:00:00.000 8
2017-03-23 00:00:00.000 13
2017-03-24 00:00:00.000 13
2017-03-25 00:00:00.000 9
2017-03-26 00:00:00.000 12
2017-03-27 00:00:00.000 12
```

thank you in advance

Comment: [xkcd PSA ISO 8601](https://xkcd.com/1179/)

Answer (score 2):

using [**`sum() over()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) for a running total, after providing a way to source the "order point":

```
declare @orderpoint table ([StockDate] [datetime] NULL, [stock] [int]);
insert into @orderpoint values 
 ('20170323',10)
,('20170326',10);

select *
  , RunningTotal = sum(stock) over (order by stockdate)
from (
    select s.stockdate, stock = s.stock+isnull(o.stock,'')
    from @stock s
      left join @orderpoint o
        on s.stockdate = o.stockdate
   ) t
order by stockdate
```

rextester **demo**: http://rextester.com/GHHU68033

returns:

```
+------------+-------+--------------+
| stockdate  | stock | RunningTotal |
+------------+-------+--------------+
| 2017-03-20 |    12 |           12 |
| 2017-03-21 |    -3 |            9 |
| 2017-03-22 |    -1 |            8 |
| 2017-03-23 |     5 |           13 |
| 2017-03-24 |     0 |           13 |
| 2017-03-25 |    -4 |            9 |
| 2017-03-26 |     3 |           12 |
| 2017-03-27 |     0 |           12 |
+------------+-------+--------------+
```

---

And for the `update`, you could use a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

```
;with cte as (
  select 
      stockdate = convert(varchar(10),stockdate,120)
    , stock
    , RunningTotal = sum(stock) over (order by stockdate)
  from (
      select s.stockdate, stock = s.stock+isnull(o.stock,'')
      from @stock s
        left join @orderpoint o
          on s.stockdate = o.stockdate
     ) t
)
update s
  set stock = cte.stock
from @stock s
  inner join cte
    on s.stockdate = cte.stockdate;

select 
    stockdate = convert(varchar(10),stockdate,120)
  , stock
from @stock;
```

returns:

```
+------------+-------+
| stockdate  | stock |
+------------+-------+
| 2017-03-20 |    12 |
| 2017-03-21 |     9 |
| 2017-03-22 |     8 |
| 2017-03-23 |    13 |
| 2017-03-24 |    13 |
| 2017-03-25 |     9 |
| 2017-03-26 |    12 |
| 2017-03-27 |    12 |
+------------+-------+
```